# How to change Grouped Barplot (multiple Barplot) labels?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I have a multiple bar plot with 5 bar plots.

```
barplot1=c(8,3,4,1) 
barplot2=c(18,11,11,13)
barplot3=c(39,42,42,45)
barplot4=c(26,30,31,34)
barplot5=c(9,13,12,7)
data <- data.frame(barplot1,barplot2,barplot3,barplot4,barplot5)
percantage <- 50
# plotting multiple bar plots
barplot(as.matrix(data),
        main="", yaxp=c(0, max(percantage), 5),
        col = c("#b62528","#f49401","#f9e536","#018404"),
        ylab="Percentage", xlab = "Elevation [m. a. s. l.]",
        beside=T,
        legend.text = c("CR","EN","VU","LC or NT"),
      
        args.legend=list(bty="n",horiz=F, x="topright", inset = c(- 0.05, -0.1)),
)
```

[image: Multiple Barplot]

How can I display the corresponding number above each Bar? And how can I include a label for each bar plot instead of the "barplot1, barplot2, barplot3, barplot4 and barplot5" expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code where we can use `names.arg` and `text` to get the expected output

```r
barplot1=c(8,3,4,1) 
barplot2=c(18,11,11,13)
barplot3=c(39,42,42,45)
barplot4=c(26,30,31,34)
barplot5=c(9,13,12,7)
data <- data.frame(barplot1,barplot2,barplot3,barplot4,barplot5)
percantage <- 55
# plotting multiple bar plots
bar <- barplot(as.matrix(data),
               main="", ylim = c(0,percantage),
               col = c("#b62528","#f49401","#f9e536","#018404"),
               ylab="Percentage", xlab = "Elevation [m. a. s. l.]",
               beside=T,
               legend.text = c("CR","EN","VU","LC or NT"),
               names.arg=c("group1","group2","group3","group4","group5"),
               args.legend=list(bty="n",horiz=F, x="topright", inset = c(- 0.05, -0.1)),
)
text(bar, as.matrix(data) + 2, labels = as.matrix(data))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `names.arg` argument.

```
labels = c("label1", "label2", "label3", "label4", "label5")
percantage <- 50
# plotting multiple bar plots
barplot(as.matrix(data),
        main="", yaxp=c(0, max(percantage), 5),
        col = c("#b62528","#f49401","#f9e536","#018404"),
        ylab="Percentage", xlab = "Elevation [m. a. s. l.]",
        beside=T,
        legend.text = c("CR","EN","VU","LC or NT"),
        names.arg = labels,
        args.legend=list(bty="n",horiz=F, x="topright", inset = c(- 0.05, -0.1)),
)
```

[image: Labeled barplot]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `text` with all the values in your dataframe as a vector by converting your data to a longer format using `pivot_longer` and assign them to each bar like this:

```r
barplot1=c(8,3,4,1) 
barplot2=c(18,11,11,13)
barplot3=c(39,42,42,45)
barplot4=c(26,30,31,34)
barplot5=c(9,13,12,7)
data <- data.frame(barplot1,barplot2,barplot3,barplot4,barplot5)
percantage <- 50
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
values <- data %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% arrange(name)
# plotting multiple bar plots
plot = barplot(as.matrix(data),
        main="", yaxp=c(0, max(percantage), 5),
        col = c("#b62528","#f49401","#f9e536","#018404"),
        ylab="Percentage", xlab = "Elevation [m. a. s. l.]",
        beside=T,
        legend.text = c("CR","EN","VU","LC or NT"),
        ylim = c(0, 50),
        args.legend=list(bty="n",horiz=F, x="topright", inset = c(-0.05, -0.1)),
)
text(x = plot, y = values$value, label = values$value, pos = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

To add percentage to labels you could use `paste0` with percent sign like this:

```r
plot = barplot(as.matrix(data),
        main="", yaxp=c(0, max(percantage), 5),
        col = c("#b62528","#f49401","#f9e536","#018404"),
        ylab="Percentage", xlab = "Elevation [m. a. s. l.]",
        beside=T,
        legend.text = c("CR","EN","VU","LC or NT"),
        ylim = c(0, 50),
        args.legend=list(bty="n",horiz=F, x="topright", inset = c(-0.05, -0.1)),
)
text(x = plot, y = values$value, label = paste0(values$value, "%"), pos = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks, How can I add "%" to each values above the bar?

Comment: Hi @SinaKh., Please see edit above. You could use `paste0`.